# Exporting from Illustrator is pixelated

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pixelation

I am trying to export sprites from illustrator so I can later import them to unity. I have a ring asset that I am trying to export. The steps I followed:
- Draw a circle (250 by 250 px and 3px black outline as shown in the screenshot)
- Draw an artboard (256px by 256px)
- Go to File -> Export -> Export for Screens 
- Make Scale 4x and the Format as png
- Export Artboard.

Even though I tried different variations, the output is always pixelated on the edge as shown in the image. (Even when I export with scale of 1x)

1- Illustrator
[image: The image in illustrator]

2- Actual Png
[image: The actual png]

3- Screenshot for how I see it on my computer (pixelated) without zooming here
[image: Screenshot from my computer how it's looking pixelated to me]

4- Screenshot for how it looks in unity (scaled down to 0.5, 0.375 and 0.25)
[image: Screenshot from unity pixelated]

Comment: Pixelated =aliased?

Comment: yes that is what I mean

Comment: Can you please share the actual PNG output.  A screen shot is not enough to tell if there's anything wrong with it.

Comment: It is shared too already as number 2- actual png :)

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean. When you export your image as a png it *does* become "pixelated" - it consists of pixels - that's the whole idea. I can't see how it looks wrong. Does it look better at the same scale in Illustrator? Can you post an image of a circle at the same scale which looks like you'd expect? Also I've opened image 2 and 3 in Photoshop and it seems that they are not in the same scale. Image 3 is slightly smaller, which ruins the anti-aliasing along the border a little bit.

Comment: You *are* aware that *everything* displayed on a monitor uses pixels, right?